# "Failed to find data source: mongodb" in Spark MongoDB connector V10

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, streaming

I am having a problem connecting to MongoDB using Spark Structured Streaming.

Here is my Python code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# from lib.logger import Log4j

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = (SparkSession
        .builder
        .appName("Streaming from mongo db")
        .master("local[3]")
        .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_10.0.5:3.3.1')
        .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true")
        # .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 3)
        .getOrCreate())

    read_from_mongo = (spark
        .readStream
        .format("mongodb")
        .option("uri", "mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017")
        .option("database", "first_db")
        .option("collection", "first_collection")
        .load()
        .writeStream
        .format("console")
        .trigger(continuous="1 second")
        .outputMode("append"))

    y = read_from_mongo.start()
```

I am running the script using `spark-submit file_name.py`. The output I'm getting is the following:

```
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.1
22/11/16 16:04:21 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Streaming from mongo db
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: mustaphaaminedebbih
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: mustaphaaminedebbih
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(mustaphaaminedebbih); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(mustaphaaminedebbih); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 52063.
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
22/11/16 16:04:21 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/yt/jz2t42md7qx68kjlydk19x5w0000gn/T/blockmgr-53c25f51-35a7-44ab-bc1d-bb16a7ae050c
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 434.4 MiB
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host 192.168.9.44
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO Executor: Starting executor with user classpath (userClassPathFirst = false): ''
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 52065.
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.9.44:52065
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.9.44, 52065, None)
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.9.44:52065 with 434.4 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.9.44, 52065, None)
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.9.44, 52065, None)
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.9.44, 52065, None)
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
22/11/16 16:04:22 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/Users/mustaphaaminedebbih/Desktop/Scrambling/Spark%20Streaming/Streaming%20From%20Mongodb/spark-warehouse'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mustaphaaminedebbih/Desktop/Scrambling/Spark Streaming/Streaming From Mongodb/test.py", line 19, in <module>
read_from_mongo = (spark
File "/Users/mustaphaaminedebbih/spark3/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 469, in load
File "/Users/mustaphaaminedebbih/spark3/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
File "/Users/mustaphaaminedebbih/spark3/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
File "/Users/mustaphaaminedebbih/spark3/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: mongodb. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:587)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:675)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.loadInternal(DataStreamReader.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:144)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mongodb.DefaultSource
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:661)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:661)
at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:661)
14 more

22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.9.44:4040
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/yt/jz2t42md7qx68kjlydk19x5w0000gn/T/spark-2ac1c680-c1d8-46e1-bfae-40c82cee015f
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/yt/jz2t42md7qx68kjlydk19x5w0000gn/T/spark-1816dfc9-2a95-4361-88d1-025c999f1514
22/11/16 16:04:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/yt/jz2t42md7qx68kjlydk19x5w0000gn/T/spark-1816dfc9-2a95-4361-88d1-025c999f1514/pyspark-095a2954-0010-4da3-b658-2483dcc79afc
```

I tried almost every possible solution, but nothing worked

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

You need to also download all the dependencies (.jars) from the pom.xml file of the mongo-spark-connector you mentioned. For example you will also need the jar file of mongo java driver in the proper version aligned to your spark-connector version.